# Mongoose insert empty Object in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update collection using mongoose with NodeJS .when I log data to NodeJs console it prints the data but not data is not being pushed in collection.
But when i run the same query on mongodb console then it works
Here's the code

> portoflio is array of objects
>
> portfolio_user={
>               'title' : 'this is the sample link',
>               'type" : 'link',
>               'url" : 'www.emumba.com'
>    }

```
var user_id=req.user._id;
console.log(user_id);
var portfolio_user=req.body;
console.log(portfolio_user)
 User.update({_id:user_id},{
    $push:{
        "portfolio":portfolio_user
    }
},
function(err, user){
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(user);
        res.jsonp(user);
    }
});
```

Note: I have also tried **findOneAndUpdate** and **findById** but they still dont work

Comment: `.update()` does not return the modified document. When you use `.findOneAndUpdate()` or `.findByIdAndUpdate()` you need to provide `{ new: true }` as the third argument. Otherwise the returned result is the original document before modification.

Comment: i have tried your appraoch it still doesn't work and My issue is element is not updated with the provided object it insert empty object

Comment: Edit your question to show what is being passed in an what the document looks like after update. When you write `function(err, user)` as the callback to the `.update()` method, then it "looks like" you were expecting a returned document. So `console.log(req.body)` before you do anything. And make some changes to your question to show what is going on.

Comment: Also add your schema.